# Boost ASIO, how to obtain the time after wait()? in c++

Tags: c++, boost

So let's say I have this simple main method :

```
        int main()
        {
          int altitude = 10;//in feet
          int altitude_rate = 3; //in feet/sec
          int new_altitude;

          boost::asio::io_service io;
          boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
          t.wait();

          new_altitude = altitude + (altitude_rate * 5(seconds));
          //I want to take the time I asked it to wait(5 sec in this case) and use it to 
          //calculate my new altitude.

          std::cout << "New Altitude: " << new_altitude << std::endl;

          return 0;
        }
```

Is there a function that can allow me to take this time out and use it like an `int`?

Comment: What do you mean "extract the 5 seconds"? Extract from where? A pocket of subspace? You want to "use this 5 seconds" how? To do work during it? Or you just want the value? What value? The five seconds for which the `deadline_timer` actually wait, or the five seconds you asked it to wait (which may not be the same value)?

Comment: There's a [`second()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_duration) function to obtain the number of seconds from a `boost::posix_time::time_duration` instance. There's also a function [`expires_from_now()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_from_now.html) to obtain the duration value when the timer will expire. It's absolutely unclear what you're actually asking about.

Comment: The 5 seconds I asked it to wait. Like after waiting the 5 sec, I would do something like `int a = (5 sec) + 10;` Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @KH17: Um well you know you asked it to wait for five seconds, because... you're the one who asked it to wait for five seconds......??? Why do you need to obtain that data from anywhere? It's already an intrinsic part of _your_ program.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit haha yeah this is just an example. The program I am working on is a bit more complicated than that. but all I need to know is how to get the time. The time could be 5/10/15 sec etc. Nevertheless I have to take that value and do some calculations with it.

Comment: @KH17: Still. Your program knew to pass 5 seconds. Or 10. Or 15. So by the same logic it knows how many seconds it passed...... What am I missing here? It's like you're saying "How can I find what I passed to `f`? `int a = 5; f(a);`" <-- you _know_ what you passed to `f` ... it's `a`........

Comment: yes you're right. I want to know the proper syntax to write it out. like the equivalent of your `f(a)` but for the time. you know what I mean? Im sorry Im really not trying to confuse you. 
 `expires_from_now()` seems to be working. I just need to convert it to int...

Comment: `const int a = 5; boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(a));` then use `a`? I really don't get it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`deadline_timer` uses an expiry time internally and so will add the delay you want (5 seconds) to the current time at construction. `expires_from_now()` will return the remaining time before it expires (which can be negative if it already fired). Therefore, you cannot get back the delay you initially gave.

You can either remember the time at which you constructed the timer and use that with `expires_at()` to figure out the initial delay, or you can just keep the delay somewhere and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Is that possible for you to use the time difference to calculate the time gap

```
boost::posix_time::ptime tick = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
// here's the deadline_timer waiting
boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
boost::posix_time::time_duration diff = now-tick;
int sec = diff.total_seconds();
```